# How to filter and downcast Swift dictionary

Tags: swift

I have 2 arrays.

```
var libraryArray = [[String: Any]()]
var searchedArray = [[String: Any]()]
```

I'm trying to set search bar functionality but all time it shows different errors.

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
 
    searchedArray = downloadManager.libraryArray.filter({($0["title"] as? String)?.prefix(searchText.count) == searchText})

    songsTableView.reloadData()
}
```

It shows "Cannot subscript a value of incorrect or ambiguous type" error.

I tried to map first and then filter but it doesn't work (maybe I wrote something wrong).

And here is an example of my "libraryArray"

```swift
[
"link": https://www.youtube.com/embed/Fm8FJ8la2VU, 
"id": yt_Fm8FJ8la2VUJHIBDACDIFJFB, 
"duration": 00:47, 
"artists": <__NSCFArray 0x6000012a1140>(), 
"fileExtension": m4a, 
"title": "Amazing Jumbo Elephant Landing"
]
```

Comment: Have you thought of making dedicated classes instead of using a `[String: Any]` dic to story your data? Classes may be `Artist` or `Album`

Comment: I need to represent data from one array. Logic is very huge and I think it's not the best solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more efficient way to filter the array and to handle the optionals is `range(of: options:`.

And you have to consider the case that `searchText` is empty to display the full array

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
     if searchText.isEmpty {
         searchedArray = downloadManager.libraryArray
     } else {
         searchedArray = downloadManager.libraryArray.filter{ ($0["title"] as? String)?.range(of: searchText, options: [.caseInsensitive, .anchored]) != nil }
     }
     songsTableView.reloadData()
}
```

I highly recommend to replace the `[String:Any]` dictionary with a custom struct to get rid of all the conditional downcasts.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
searchedArray = downloadManager.libraryArray.filter({($0["title"] as? String)?.prefix(searchText.count) == searchText})
```

to

```
    searchedArray = libraryArray.filter({ (element) -> Bool in
        guard let value = element["title"] as? String else {
            return false
        }
        return value.prefix(searchText.count) == searchText
    })
```

Then your compiler won't complain anymore. Tested in playground, Xcode version 11.6. I do think it may be related to swift type inference itself. Maybe other guys can explain it more specifically.